# SQL output to display parent child relationships 4 levels deep

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a resource table that contains resource values and descriptions. The table also has a parent_id column that can match a res_id of another resource. This table can go up to 4 levels deep of children.

Sample resource table:

```
| res_id| kind_id| value         | description | parent_id|
|-------|--------|---------------|-------------|----------|
| 5678  | 4      | price_asfa    | fgdfhdf     | null     |
| 6789  | 2      | number_val    | djhhjhj     | 2345     |
| 9876  | 5      | test_val      | lutuyutyu   | 5678     |
| 8765  | 2      | other_val     | yuiyuiy     | 9876     |
| 26346 | 3      | edit_kind     | yfgjqwes    | null     |
| 1234  | 2      | option_kind   | dggdfghdhg  | 2345     |
| 2345  | 3      | fruit_price   | ghfgndfd    | 3456     |
| 3456  | 5      | console_price | fgdfgdsffhg | 5678     |
```

I also have a users table and a many-many user_resource table to create a relationship between the user_id and the res_id

Sample user table:

```
| user_id | username  | password | user_type_id |
|---------|-----------|----------|--------------|
| 100     | tim.smith | sdfsg    | 5            |
| 200     | jon.doe   | sdfsdh   | 4            |
| 300     | alex.din  | tyurte   | 5            |
```

Sample user_resource table

```
| user_id | res_id | date |
|---------|--------|------|
| 100     | 3456   | any  |
| 300     | 1234   | any  |
| 200     | 8765   | any  |
| 100     | 26346  | any  |
```

Im looking to get an SQL output where each row can see the username and userid as well as 4 columns (one column for each level resource description). not all resources will go 4 levels deep so some columns will have null values.

Im running into a situation when trying to join all the tables that im seeing duplicate resources moved up one level in the column rows. So im trying to nest the resource selects but its causing issues and im not able to create this table.

Expected output. (basically break down the relationships in the resource table into 4 columns as its max only 4 levels deep on parent/child/grandchild):

```
| user_id | username  | resource_group | resource1   | resource2     | resource3  |
|---------|-----------|----------------|-------------|---------------|------------|
| 100     | tim.smith | console_price  | price_asfa  | null          | null       |
| 100     | tim.smith | edit_kind      | null        | null          | null       |
| 200     | jon.doe   | other_val      | test_val    | price_asfa    | null       |
| 300     | alex.din  | option_kind    | fruit_price | console_price | price_asfa |
| 300     | alex.din  | edit_kind      | null        | null          | null       |
```

Ive made it one level down, but now if i try to nest a select join inside the other select join im getting invalid identifier errors as i guess the query cant find the nested values?

How can i keep this query going all the way down 4 levels?

```
SELECT u.userid,
       u.username,
       r.resource_group AS "RESOURCE GROUP",
       r.resource1
FROM   users_table u
       inner join user_resources_table ur
               ON u.userid = ur.userid
       left join (SELECT r1.resid,
                         r1.description  RESOURCE_GROUP,
                         r_r.description resource1
                  FROM   resources_table r1
                         left join resources_table r_r
                                ON r_r.parentid = r1.resid
                  WHERE  r1.parentid IS NULL) r
              ON ur.resid = r.resid
WHERE  u.active = 'Y'
       AND u.usertypeid = 5
       AND u.username = 'someName'
ORDER  BY u.username,
          r.resource_group,
          r.resource1;
```

EDIT: update to Alex's response.

Currently now if I run the query as you've given alex i end up with something like this ():

```
| user_id | username  | resource_group | resource1     | resource2   | resource3     |
|---------|-----------|----------------|---------------|-------------|---------------|
| 100     | tim.smith | null           | null          | price_asafa | console_price |
| 100     | tim.smith | null           | null          | null        | edit_kind     |
| 200     | jon.doe   | null           | price_asfa    | test_val    | other_val     |
| 300     | alex.din  | price_asfa     | console_price | fruit_price | option_kind   |
| 300     | alex.din  | null           | null          | null        | edit_kind     |
```

When its supposed to be like this:

```
| user_id | username  | resource_group | resource1   | resource2     | resource3  |
|---------|-----------|----------------|-------------|---------------|------------|
| 100     | tim.smith | console_price  | price_asfa  | null          | null       |
| 100     | tim.smith | edit_kind      | null        | null          | null       |
| 200     | jon.doe   | other_val      | test_val    | price_asfa    | null       |
| 300     | alex.din  | option_kind    | fruit_price | console_price | price_asfa |
| 300     | alex.din  | edit_kind      | null        | null          | null       |
```

So i reversed the lvl like so:

```
for lvl in (3 as grp, 2 as lvl1, 1 as lvl2, 0 as lvl3)
```

And now it is aligning like below:

```
| user_id | username  | resource_group | resource1   | resource2     | resource3  |
|---------|-----------|----------------|-------------|---------------|------------|
| 100     | tim.smith | null           | null        | console_price | price_asfa |
| 100     | tim.smith | null           | null        | null          | edit_kind  |
| 200     | jon.doe   | null           | other_val   | test_val      | price_asfa |
| 300     | alex.din  | option_kind    | fruit_price | console_price | price_asfa |
| 300     | alex.din  | null           | null        | null          | edit_kind  |
```

Which works if all rows are not null. but any nulls end up by default to the left of the data. See the first row for example. The values should be in resource_group and resource1 as noted in the example table above, but they are aligned on the right of the table.

Is there a way to reverse this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recursive subquery factoring to generate the levels:

```
with rcte (user_id, username, root_res_id, lvl, res_id, parent_id, value) as (
  select ut.user_id, ut.username, urt.res_id, 0, rt.res_id, rt.parent_id, rt.value
  from users_table ut
  join user_resources_table urt on urt.user_id = ut.user_id
  join resources_table rt on rt.res_id = urt.res_id
  union all
  select r.user_id, r.username, r.root_res_id, r.lvl + 1, rt.res_id, rt.parent_id, rt.value
  from rcte r
  join resources_table rt on rt.res_id = r.parent_id
)
select * from rcte
```

| USER_ID | USERNAME | ROOT_RES_ID | LVL | RES_ID | PARENT_ID | VALUE | DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | tim.smith | 3456 | 1 | 3456 | 5678 | console_price | fgdfgdsffhg |
| 100 | tim.smith | 3456 | 2 | 5678 | *null* | price_asfa | fgdfhdf |
| 100 | tim.smith | 26346 | 1 | 26346 | *null* | edit_kind | yfgjqwes |
| 200 | jon.doe | 8765 | 1 | 8765 | 9876 | other_val | yuiyuiy |
| 200 | jon.doe | 8765 | 2 | 9876 | 5678 | test_val | lutuyutyu |
| 200 | jon.doe | 8765 | 3 | 5678 | *null* | price_asfa | fgdfhdf |
| 300 | alex.din | 1234 | 1 | 1234 | 2345 | option_kind | dggdfghdhg |
| 300 | alex.din | 1234 | 2 | 2345 | 3456 | fruit_price | ghfgndfd |
| 300 | alex.din | 1234 | 3 | 3456 | 5678 | console_price | fgdfgdsffhg |
| 300 | alex.din | 1234 | 4 | 5678 | *null* | price_asfa | fgdfhdf |

And then pivot using the levels to get the format you want, renaming the pivoted columns to whatever you want:

```
with rcte (user_id, username, root_res_id, lvl, res_id, parent_id, value) as (
  select ut.user_id, ut.username, urt.res_id, 0, rt.res_id, rt.parent_id, rt.value
  from users_table ut
  join user_resources_table urt on urt.user_id = ut.user_id
  join resources_table rt on rt.res_id = urt.res_id
  union all
  select r.user_id, r.username, r.root_res_id, r.lvl + 1, rt.res_id, rt.parent_id, rt.value
  from rcte r
  join resources_table rt on rt.res_id = r.parent_id
)
select user_id, username,
  grp_value as resource_group,
  lvl1_value as resource_1,
  lvl2_value as resource_2,
  lvl3_value as resource_3
from (
  select user_id, username, root_res_id, lvl, res_id, value
  from rcte
)
pivot (
  max(res_id) as res_id, max(value) as value 
  for lvl in (0 as grp, 1 as lvl1, 2 as lvl2, 3 as lvl3)
)
order by user_id, root_res_id
```

| USER_ID | USERNAME | RESOURCE_GROUP | RESOURCE_1 | RESOURCE_2 | RESOURCE_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | tim.smith | console_price | price_asfa | *null* | *null* |
| 100 | tim.smith | edit_kind | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 200 | jon.doe | other_val | test_val | price_asfa | *null* |
| 300 | alex.din | option_kind | fruit_price | console_price | price_asfa |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=98fba57eaf5c617199239d0f680f0b3a)

---

If you want to reverse the order so that the resource at the root of the hierarchy - that is, the one with a null parent - as the resource group, then you can reverse the levels in the pivot subquery (*not* in the pivot clause itself):

```
with rcte (user_id, username, root_res_id, lvl, res_id, parent_id, value) as (
  select ut.user_id, ut.username, urt.res_id, 0, rt.res_id, rt.parent_id, rt.value
  from users_table ut
  join user_resources_table urt on urt.user_id = ut.user_id
  join resources_table rt on rt.res_id = urt.res_id
  union all
  select r.user_id, r.username, r.root_res_id, r.lvl + 1, rt.res_id, rt.parent_id, rt.value
  from rcte r
  join resources_table rt on rt.res_id = r.parent_id
)
select user_id, username,
  grp_value as resource_group,
  lvl1_value as resource_1,
  lvl2_value as resource_2,
  lvl3_value as resource_3
from (
  select user_id, username, root_res_id, res_id, value,
    row_number() over (partition by user_id, root_res_id order by lvl desc) - 1 as lvl
  from rcte
)
pivot (
  max(res_id) as res_id, max(value) as value 
  for lvl in (0 as grp, 1 as lvl1, 2 as lvl2, 3 as lvl3)
)
order by user_id, root_res_id
```

| USER_ID | USERNAME | RESOURCE_GROUP | RESOURCE_1 | RESOURCE_2 | RESOURCE_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | tim.smith | price_asfa | console_price | *null* | *null* |
| 100 | tim.smith | edit_kind | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 200 | jon.doe | price_asfa | test_val | other_val | *null* |
| 300 | alex.din | price_asfa | console_price | fruit_price | option_kind |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=61ed51c5471dd46a2129c8f22a92729e)

But that isn't what you showed in the question.

Comment: I appreciate this, its much closer to fixing my issue. However this code is aligning my actual output backwords. where group is in resource3 column, resource 1 is in resource 2 etc. 

So i tried to change the numbers around in: for lvl in this sections to: (3 as grp, 2 as lvl1, 1 as lvl2, 0 as lvl3). this has now placed the resources in their proper direction in the row. But now data is filling from right to left. for example if there is only 2 resources (including group) they will be in columns resource_2 and resource_3 instead of resource_group_ and resource_1

Comment: I based this on your example. (Though you have an extra row for 300; not sure if that shouldn't be there, or you missed a row in user_resources_table?) You may just need to change the recursive member's join condition from `rt.res_id = r.parent_id` to `rt.parent_id = r.res_id` - but with your sample [that doesn't produce much](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=ef6dcfa9f3a4d19cc4474b3c9b15ae19). Maybe it does with your real data though.

Comment: Ive edited the question to display the issues and what i changed to change the issue around. I cant figure out why its not aligning from resource group first then down through res 1, 2, and finally 3

Comment: I showed the output you said you wanted in the question. Perhaps you want 'root' resource first, reversing the order? That isn't what you showed, but I added a way to do that.

Comment: Correct, my question was wrong, I do want the root resource first. Which is probably why im getting so many issues with this. The new line now gives me, "column ambiguously defined". Ill keep plugging at it though and accept the answer once something similar works

Comment: @elementmg - if you mean the new `row_number()` line, did you remove the plain `lvl` from the previous line? I've aliased that expression as `lvl` and it can't have two with the same name - but the original isn't needed by the pivot clause.

Comment: Thats it!

Thank you so much Alex, you've been incredibly helpful and have taught me a lot. ill be studying this query to really learn everything you've done. 

Cheers.

Comment: Alex, I noticed in my user table that there is also a parent id. This means the users have group just the same as resource groups. So users parent id will go to a group which can also go 4 levels of groups. all in the same user table.
Im checking to try and add the user group columns to the final output but looks like pivot cant be used for both? Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: @elementmg - you will need to ask a new question, explaining all of that fully and with sample data and expected results, plus your best effort and the problem you are having. It's too much for comments.

Answer (score 2):

Almost exactly the same as my answer to [your (now deleted) previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73466094/1509264), just reversing the hierarchy and then re-reversing the depths:

```sql
select u.user_id,
       u.username,
       r.*
FROM   users_table u
       INNER JOIN user_resources_table ur
       on u.user_id  = ur.user_id
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT *
         FROM   (
           SELECT value,
                  MAX(LEVEL) OVER () + 1 - LEVEL AS depth
           FROM   resources_table r
           WHERE  level <= 4
           START WITH ur.res_id = r.res_id
           CONNECT BY res_id = PRIOR parent_id
         )
         PIVOT (
           MAX(value)
           FOR depth IN (
             1 AS resource_group,
             2 AS resource1,
             3 AS resource2,
             4 AS resource3
           )
         )
       ) r
--WHERE  u.active = 'Y'
--AND    u.user_type_id = 5
--AND    u.username = 'someName'
ORDER BY
       u.username,
       r.resource_group,
       r.resource1,
       r.resource2,
       r.resource3;
```

Which, for the sample data (thanks @AlexPoole), outputs:

> | USER_ID | USERNAME | RESOURCE_GROUP | RESOURCE1 | RESOURCE2 | RESOURCE3 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 300 | alex.din | price_asfa | console_price | fruit_price | option_kind |
> | 200 | jon.doe | price_asfa | test_val | other_val | *null* |
> | 100 | tim.smith | edit_kind | *null* | *null* | *null* |
> | 100 | tim.smith | price_asfa | console_price | *null* | *null* |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=8bd393aaf8eb5b38f310bfd01151bc80)*

Comment: Again, im having the same invalid identifier issues with your response at the START WITH ur.res_id.